# Part time - pay related

Tags: salary, part-time

I have been asked by an employer to work for part time (remotely). I informed the employer of my available timings. They said ok and introduced me to their team, created an email address, and the daily meetings are going on.

Everything seems to be going well but when I asked for a system to work with, as I need a system that supports development configuration, they said that they would look for it later. Daily action items are coming in meetings and I am adjusting in my old low configuration system. Most importantly, they haven't brought up any payment related discussions yet. It's been almost 10 days since I've been working with them.

During the initial discussion, we've not spoken about the payment aspects. Can I directly ask about the pay at least now or wait for few more days to get a reply from the employer?

Comment: "(nearly 10 days from initial starting of work)..." Does this mean you started working 10 days ago or that you're scheduled to start working 10 days after today?

Comment: I am working from last 10 days. Team is setting up meetings, i am working on mockups etc.

Comment: In that case, Jane S is absolutely right. Stop working until you agree on a salary and receive a signed contract.

Comment: Congratulations, you have been tricked into working for free.

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean you started working for someone without actually having a written contract on the amount you will be paid?

You need to stop work right now and sort that out and signed on paper.  If you haven't agreed on pricing then they can easily say that you agreed to work for nothing and you have absolutely nothing to say otherwise.

Never commence any job, full time or part time, until you have a written contract including remuneration in place.